# $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ whose sum is prime implied $\gcd(a,b) = 1$.

Tags: solution-verification, gcd-and-lcm

I was hoping someone could let me know whether the logic in this proof is sound.

> Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers whose sum is a prime, $p$.  Prove that $\gcd(a,b) = 1$.

Define $d = \gcd(a,b)$. By definition, $d \mid a$ and $d \mid b$, so $d \mid a + b$. That is, $d \mid p$. The only positive divisors of $p$, since it is prime, are $1$ and $p$. For a contradiction, suppose $d = p$. Then $p \mid a$ and $p \mid b$, so there exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that $p = ax$ and $p = by$. So 
$$p = ax = by$$
and
$$ 
a + b = ax + by.
$$
Since $a$ and $b$ are positive, and hence $p$ is positive, $ax$ and $by$ must be positive. Hence, $x = y = 1$ is the only possibility. Hence, 
$$p = a = b.$$
Hence, 
$$a + b = p + p = 2p$$
But $a + b = p$, so 
$$p = 2p,$$
which implies that $p = \frac{1}{2}$, which is absurd.

Comment: not too straightforward but the logic in the proof is solid. shorther one will be to write $a$ and $b$ as $a=dm$ and $b=dn$ with $m,n\in{Z^{+}}$ therefore $p=d(m+n)$ since $m+n>1$ the only solution is $d=1$, $m+n=p$

Comment: This makes sense intuitively, but would you mind explaining how we can deduce that the only solution to that equation is $d = 1$? I want to say something to the effect of $m + n > 1$ and $p \geq 1$ (since $d = p$ or $d = 1$ since $d$ divides $p$), so $p(m+n) > p$. I can't think of a way to do that without appealing to intuition about arithmetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "For a contradiction, suppose d=p. Then p∣a and p∣b, so there exist integers x and y such that p=ax and p=by"

No! the exact opposite!

$p|a$ so there exist a positive integer, $x$ so that $a = px$ and $p|b$ means there is a positive integer $y$ so that $b=px$.

So.....  $p = a+b = px+py = p(x+y)$ so $x + y = 1$.  But $x \ge 1$ and $y \ge 1$ and so $x+y \ge 2$. Our contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is correct, but as $p$ divides $a$ and $b$, I think you meant to write $$\exists x,y\in\mathbb{Z} \ \text{such that}\ a=px,\ b=py.$$
This gives then
$$p=a+b=p(x+y)$$
which is a contradiction as $p,x,$ and $y$ are positive integers.